# How to use inheritance in JPA with a given SQL model

Tags: java, jpa

I have 3 tables:

`Person` with attributes: `Id`, `name`

`Client` with attributes: `Id`, `product_id`

`Employee` with attributes: `Id`, `task`

The `id` is their primary key, and since is a one-to-one relationship, I would like to add a foreign key from client `Id` to Person's `id` and Employee's `id` to Person's `id`.

How do I implement this in JPA? I found that inheritance could be done with `@MappedSuperClass` but in this particular case I have a table `Person`.

I could just delete the Person table and add each attribute to Client and Employee, but i'm pretty sure it wouldn't be a good choice for scaling.

Is there any way to properly implement this model?

Comment: Why not simply use a `OneToOne` mapping, so that `Client` holds an instance of `Person`, and similar with `Employee`?

Comment: On one side you are talking about inheritance and on the other side you are talking about one-to-one relationship. It is not clear what you want. Do you mean `Person` is parent of `Cleint` and `Employee`?

Comment: @ujulu Since there is no hierarchy in SQL, the only way to represent this is by having one to one rerlationship with the main table and every subtable have an attribute that differentiates it. In this case, Person is the main table, Client and Employe are the subtables with their respective own attributes. My problem is that I dont know how to model this in JPA. I want only to persist a Client or an Employee.

Comment: @rrrub I meant the domain semantic and not the database implementation.